# How to remove empty array spaces in .split() with a regex condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the following string at the "Chan #: " with an optional comma "," just before ",Chan #: "

```
Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59
```

I am currently using this regex:

```
var x = values.value;
var v = x.split(/\b[,]?Chan\s+\d+:\s+([\s\d.]+)/g);
console.log(v.length);
console.log(v[0]);
console.log(v[1]);
console.log(v[2]);
console.log(v[3]);
console.log(v[4]);
console.log(v[5]);
console.log(v[6]);
console.log(v[7]);
console.log(v[8]);
```

The expected output is an array with a size of 4 with each channels' corresponding 4 numbers. However I am getting an array with the size of 9: https://imgur.com/41Hs0cy

Comment: You already have a solution in your previous question. It is not a single-pass solution, you must split the values captured in Group 1 with whitespace. If you need more clarification, just drop a comment under the answer.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Array#filter` .recreate the array with valid arguments

```js
var x = 'Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59';
var v = x.split(/\b[,]?Chan\s+\d+:\s+([\s\d.]+)/g).filter(a=> a)
console.log(v.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var v = x.split(/\b[,]?Chan\s+\d+:\s+([\s\d.]+)/g).filter(x => x !== '');
```

well,

```
.filter(x => x !== '')
```

filters all values that are empty